# I have a bug in my HTML ERB file for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a text field that accepts input and when you press the button next to it, it will save these changes to the database. It will be a PUT request, updating the value in the database for this specific user (not the logged in user, this is a page for admins to update values for users).

This is what the structure should be, (code to follow below):

1) Create text field and button for this in `show.html.erb`

2) Create a function called `set_wistia_project_ID` for this in `users_controller.rb`, set button equal to this `:action`

3) Create a helper function called `set_project_id` in `user.rb` that is called by `set_wistia_project_ID`, which actually updates the database. I decided to split it up into two functions because I noticed a lot of Rails projects tend to separate and break up functionality into the controller and model.

4) Edit my `routes.rb` to include some strange code, which I'll be honest, have no idea what it actually does. But without it, the entire app crashes on Heroku. So I leave it there. Found from a StackOverflow post.

My `show.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
        <br>
        <%= @user.email %>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
              <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

              <%= f.label :wistia_project_id %>
              <%= f.text_field :wistia_project_id, class: 'form-control' %>

              <%= button_to "Save", :action => "set_wistia_project_ID", :method => :put, :form_class => "form-control" %>   
          </div>
        </div>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

My `users_controller.rb`:

```
  # Sets wistia_project_ID.
  def set_wistia_project_ID
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.set_project_id
  end
```

My `user.rb`:

```
  # Sets the wistia_project_ID.
  def set_project_id
    self.wistia_project_ID # HOW TO SET EQUAL TO INPUT?
  end
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'
  get 'sessions/new'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      put 'set_wistia_project_ID'
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

But the problem I am having is that when I try to go to `show.html.erb`, my Heroku app crashes :(

The reason:

```
F, [2019-06-25T19:53:20.706881 #8] FATAL -- : [b2ed08bb-de52-417f-9ba8-8ec85629dce8] 
app/views/users/show.html.erb:30: 
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end
```

But it looks fine to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is that you are missing `<% end %>` for the `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>` block.

To answer your question about how to access the param in the model's method - you should pass it as an argument:

```
@user.set_project_id(params[:wistia_project_ID])
```

And change the method to accept an argument. Note, I am assuming you want to actually persist this to the database, so I'm adding a `save` call. You could alternatively call `update` which assigns the new value and saves in one go.

```
def set_project_id(val)
  self.wistia_project_ID = val # self is necessary here
  save # or self.save, but the self is unnecessary here
end
```

However, calling `save` does always *succesfully* save the record, there is still the possibility of an error if a model-level validation failed. You can handle this using `flash`: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now

or, if you don't need to redirect, can just use an instance variable to store the errors:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.set_project_id(params[:wistia_project_ID])
unless @user.valid?
  @errors = @user.errors.full_messages
  render :show
end
```

and in the `show` view:

```
<% if @errors  %>
  <p>THE FORM COULD NOT BE SAVED </p>
  <ul id='errors'>
  <% @errors.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Also note, I would probably rename your `set_project_id` method to `set_project_id!` (added a bang), to signify that it mutates the input (changes its internal state).

Comment: This `<% end %>` instead of this `<%= end %>`. (First line) :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thought-out response. I appreciate the effort you put in! One question, you mention that you pass something into ```set_project_id!(val)```, but you do not pass anything when you call it in ```@user.set_project_id```? Thank you again.

Comment: @McFloofenbork you're right, that was a typo. Edited